# What is wrong with this code... it is not returning the data?

Tags: c

```
char stringConcatenate (char y[], char z[])
{
    unsigned short int a = 0, len;
    len = stringLength(y);
    while (z[a] != '\0')
    {
        y[len + a] = z[a];
        a++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", y);
    return y;
}
```

The `return y;` is not returning the value stored in it to the function call.

Comment: A `char` pointer is not a `char`. Please enable, read and understand your compiler warnings.

Comment: `stringConcatenate ()` return type should be `char *`.

Comment: Also NUL(`'\0'`) is required at the end of the combined string. E.g `y[len+a] = '\0';` after while-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest that you first read about the basics of pointers and arrays. Check out [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm).

An array like `char y[]` is organised as a contiguous set of `char` elements, and a pointer called `y` points to the first element of the array. Since this pointer points to a `char` type, the type of the pointer itself is `char *`.

Thus, when you say `return y`, you are not returning the contents of the array `y` - you are returning the value of `y`, which is an address to the first element of the `y` array.

So the return type of your function should be `char *`.